# Rota do AngularJS não abre no carregamento da página

Tags: angularjs

Tenho um template e duas rotas, nenhuma abre no carregamento da página (ou F5), mas se eu fizer um $state.go('nomeDaRota'), ela é carregada corretamente.

```
// routes.js

angular.module('app').config([
'$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',
function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    console.log('Register routes...');

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/demo-register");

    $stateProvider.state('quickRegister', {
        url: '/quick-register',
        templateUrl: 'path/para/quick-register.html',
        controller: 'QuickRegisterController'
    }).state('demoRegister', {
        url: "/demo-register",
        templateUrl: 'path/para/demo-register.html',
        controller: 'DemoRegisterController'
    });
}]);
```

---

```
<!-- template.html -->
<div class="main" ng-controller="CleanController">
    <div id="header">
        <div class="container">
            <img ng-src="{{headerSrc}}">
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content" ui-view></div>
</div>
```

---

```
angular.module('app').controller('CleanController', [
    '$scope', '$state',
    function ($scope, $state) {
        console.log('$state.current', $state.current)
        // output: $state.current {name: "", url: "^", views: null, abstract: true}
    }
]);
```

Nota que no CleanController eu dei um console.log do *state* corrente, e ele retornou um *state* "em branco", porém em momento algum eu defini esse *state*.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como corrigir o problema?

Comment: essa função está dentro de um angular.config....

Comment: Quando você usar `state.go()` a URL muda para `~/#/quickRegister`, por exemplo?

Comment: Estou carregando a página em `localhost:3000/demo-register`,  a _ui-view_ está vazia no carregamento da página, quando eu faço o state.go('demoRegister'), a URL se mantém a mesma (estou usando modeHtml5) e a _ui-view_ é preenchida com o conteúdo de `quick-register.html`

Comment: Em modo HTML5 você precisa guarantir que chamadas a estados sejam redirecionadas, e isso ocorre no lado do servidor. Você já tem isso configurado?

Comment: Então, a minha rota no servidor que carrega esse template, é a mesma rota do front `app.get('/demo-register', ctrl.renderDemoRegister);`, que faz a renderização do template, porém após essa renderização, o angular não está entendendo a rota e está trazendo o template vazio.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver criando um *state abstract*:

```
$stateProvider.state('clean', {
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'path/para/template.html'
}).state('clean.quickRegister', {
    url: '/quick-register',
    templateUrl: 'path/para/quick-register.html',
    controller: 'QuickRegisterController'
}).state('clean.demoRegister', {
    url: "/demo-register",
    templateUrl: 'path/para/demo-register.html',
    controller: 'DemoRegisterController'
})
```